# Adaptive Server connection failed TinyTDS::error when connecting ruby on SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: ruby, t-sql, freetds, tiny-tds

I'm trying to connect my Rails app (rails version 4.2.5 and ruby 2.2.2) in Ubuntu(wsl) with my SQL SERVER 2008 R2 database.

i have tried to connect it with

```
tsql -H mydb.database.windows.net -p 1433 -U myuser@mydb -P mypassword -D 
mydb
```

but i getting this error message

```
Error 20017 (severity 9):
        Unexpected EOF from the server
Error 20002 (severity 9):
        Adaptive Server connection failed
There was a problem connecting to the server
```

Comment: Can you telnet to the server and port? `telnet mydb.database.windows.net 1433`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved

I'm using FreeTDS ver. 1.0.21, testing it with `tsql` on a console and it worked

The problem is when i used tiny_tds gem on Ruby it always give same error message like before, then i know my tds version must be set to auto and everything is going well.